# DataTables searchPanes button to filter across all columns

Tags: button, filter, datatables

I am using the Javascript library DataTables.

I added a button to open the dialog in order to filter across all columns.

So far, my code is this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
 
        buttons:[
            {
                extend: 'searchPanes',
                config: {
                    cascadePanes: true,
                    viewTotal: true,
                orderable: false
                }
            }
        ],
        searchPanes: {
          viewTotal: true,
          orderable: false
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
 
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    });
 
    dt.on('select.dt', () => {         
        dt.searchPanes.rebuildPane(0, true);
    });
 
    dt.on('deselect.dt', () => {
        dt.searchPanes.rebuildPane(0, true);
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like the button to trigger filters for all the five columns (except the title) but I only get filters for two of them.

Here is the [URL of my project](http://trovawiki.altervista.org/museo_diocesano.php) where you can see what I am getting.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `columns.searchPanes.show` option we can force all the columns to be considered.

Here is the link to the [DataTable forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/67763/searchpanes-button-to-filter-across-all-columns#latest) where the answer was given.

The code to add to the script is as follows:

```
   columnDefs: [
        {
            searchPanes: {
                show: true
            },
            targets: [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        {
            searchPanes: {
                show: false
            },
            targets: [0]
        }
    ],
```